# HTML: Does a 'disabled' attribute on non-input element invalidate your document?

Tags: html, validation, attributes

The `disabled` attribute was designed for `<input/>` elements. If I use this attribute on a non `<input/>` element, will it invalidate my document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe.

It depends on which non-input element you put it in.

[The spec has a list of attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/fullindex.html#attributes-table) which shows which elements support each one.

> disabled
>
> button; fieldset; input; optgroup; option; select; textarea